# Trying to show the differential operator $-e^{-x}\frac{d}{dx}(x\frac{df}{dx})$ is positive

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, inner-products, bilinear-form

This is a homework question.

Let:

- $V$ : $\mathbb{R}$-vector space of $C^\infty$ functions over the interval $[1,a]$ and are $0$ on the boundary of this interval
- $\langle-,-\rangle$ : be an inner product on V defined as $\langle f,g \rangle = \int^a_1f(x)g(x)e^{x}dx$
- $T \in \operatorname{End}(V)$ : $T(f)=-e^{-x}\frac{d}{dx}(x\frac{df}{dx})$

And I am to show that $T$ is a positive operator. That is, $\langle Tf,f\rangle \ge 0$  $\forall f\in V$.
So far, I have tried;

- To find $S \in V$ such that $S^2 = T$. This turned out to be harder than I thought, and I can't think of a systamtic way of doing it
- To directly use the definition of $T$ and the inner product to show $T$ is positive. This boils down to showing $\int^a_1f(f' + xf'')dx \ge 0$
- To show that no solutions to the differential equation $xe^{-x}f''+e^{-x}f'+\lambda f=0$ exist if $\lambda \lt 0$

However, I come up short on all accounts. Perhaps a nudge in the right direction? Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that there's an $e^{-x}$ in both the definition of the inner product and the definition of $T$? For things to work out, there has to be $e^x$ in one and $e^{-x}$ in the other.

Comment: @BranimirĆaćić Oops thank you. I believe you are right. I was trying to recall the question from memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\ip}[1]{\left\langle{#1}\right\rangle}$By integration by parts, we have that
$$
 \ip{f,Tf} = \int_1^a f(x) \left(-e^{-x} \left(xf^\prime(x)\right)^\prime \right) e^{x} dx = -\int_1^a f(x)\left(xf^\prime(x)\right)^\prime dx = -\left.\left(f(x)xf^\prime(x)\right)\right|_1^a+\int_1^a x \left(f^\prime(x)\right)^2 dx.
$$
What do you observe about the second term of the final expression? Moreover, given the definition of the vector space $V$, what can you observe about the first term of the final expression?

Comment: You know what. I did exactly this hours ago and noted the same thing about the first term in the final expression. I guess I was too careless in my writing and didn't notice that square in the second term of the final expression as well.. In any case, thank you for relieving me of this! Your time and help is much appreciated

Comment: can you clarify why the second term of the final expression shows that T is positive?

Comment: @anon: For $x \in [1,a]$, on the one hand, $(f^\prime(x))^2 \geq 0$ as the square of a real number, and on the other, $x \geq 1 > 0$, so that the second term is the definite integral over $[1,a]$ of a function taking non-negative values over $[1,a]$.